# Indexing into 2nd array element always returns zero

Tags: arrays, indexing, glsl, vulkan

I have an UBO that looks like this:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

const uint InstanceCount = 64;

layout(std140, align = 16, binding = 0) uniform UBO
{
    vec4 array_indices[InstanceCount];
    mat4 proj;
    mat4 model;
    mat4 models[InstanceCount];
    uint selection[128];
} ubo;
```

and each vertex shader instance accesses one bit from `uint selection[128]` like this:

```
layout(location = 1) out uint is_selected;

void main() {
    uint id = gl_InstanceIndex;
    uint num_index = id / 32;
    uint bit_index = id % uint(32);
    uint n = ubo.selection[num_index];
    is_selected = n & (1u << bit_index);
...
}
```

The problem is that whenever `id` is greater than 31 (that is when `num_index` is 1 or greater) `n` is always zero. But RenderDoc shows that the first 2 `uint`s of `ubo.selection[128]` are F0000380 and 0000000F (which means the 2nd `uint` is not zero), so I'm guessing the shader has problems indexing into the array, so any ideas why `n` is zero unless I'm indexing into the first elem of the array?

AMD Polaris10 video card.

The C++ structure which feeds this UBO is:

```
static const u32 InstanceCount = 64;

struct UBO
{
    vkm::vec4 array_indices[InstanceCount];
    vkm::mat4 proj;
    vkm::mat4 model;
    vkm::mat4 models[InstanceCount];
    u32 selection[128];
};
```

`vkm::mat4` is a class with a single member float arr[16].

Comment: How are you uploading data to the shader? That is, what is the C or C++ structure which you *think* is equivalent to the GLSL definition?

Comment: I appended the C++ structure, a padding issue is the only problem I can think of but I don't know how to fix/detect it.

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, write it as an *answer* using the Add an Answer button; don't edit it into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `std140` layout, all arrays have an element-to-element array stride rounded up to the nearest `sizeof(vec4)`, which is 16 bytes. So unless `u32` is actually a 16-byte structure, `u32 selection[128];` doesn't match with your definition.

What your GLSL needs to do is to take a `uvec4` array 4 times smaller than its actual size, and index the array like this:

```
const int num_selection_elements = 128;
const int num_selection_words = num_selection_elements / 4
layout(std140, align = 16, binding = 0) uniform UBO
{
    ...
    uvec4 selection[num_selection_words];
} ubo;

void main() {
    uint id = gl_InstanceIndex;
    uint bit_index = id % 32;
    uint word_index = (id / 32) % 4;
    uint vec_index = id / (num_selection_words * 32 * 4);
    uint n = ubo.selection[vec_index][word_index];
    is_selected = n & (1u << bit_index);
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though I tested it and the selection doesn't work at all now, though RenderDoc now says that the UBO occupies less space. I just woke up so if I have new ideas I'll share later. It's a small app (works only on Linux), should I post it somewhere so people can try compiling it?

Comment: RenderDoc says the selection array isn't empty, so could be the indexing into the array.. or some other misterios cause.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is right except for the vec array indexing which by trial and error I eventually figured out and edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

After more testing this is the final correct indexing into the array of `uvec4`:

```
uint index = gl_InstanceIndex;
const uint vec_index = index / 128; // 128 = 32 * 4 = vec size
index %= 128;
uint num_index = index / 32;
const uint bit_index = index % 32;
const uint n = ubo.selection[vec_index][num_index];
is_selected = n & (1u << bit_index);
```

That is, when indexing past the first `uvec4` `num_index` becomes wrong without `index %= 128;`.