# What use has the layout specifier scalar in EXT_scalar_block_layout?

Tags: c++, glsl, vulkan

## Question

What use has the `scalar` layout specifier when accessing a storage buffer in GL_EXT_scalar_block_layout? (see below for example)

What would be use case for `scalar`?

## Background

I recently programmed a simple Raytracer using Vulkan and NVidias VkRayTracing extension and was following [this tutorial](https://developer.nvidia.com/rtx/raytracing/vkray). In the section about the closest hit shader it is required to access some data that's stored in, well storage buffers (with usage flags `vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eStorageBuffer`).

In the shader the extension `GL_EXT_scalar_block_layout` is used and those buffers are accessed like this:

```
layout(binding = 4, set = 1, scalar) buffer Vertices { Vertex v[]; } vertices[];
```

When I first used this code the validation layers told me that the structs like `Vertex` had an invalid layout, so I changed them to have each member aligned on 16byte blocks:

```
struct Vertex {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 normal;
    vec4 texCoord;
};
```

with the corresponding struct in C++:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Vertex {
    glm::vec4 position_1unused;
    glm::vec4 normal_1unused;
    glm::vec4 texCoord_2unused;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Errors disappeared and I got a working Raytracer. But I still don't understand why the `scalar` keyword is used here. I found [this document](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/ext/GL_EXT_scalar_block_layout.txt) talking about the GL_EXT_scalar_block_layout-extension, but I really don't understand it. Probably I'm just not used to glsl terminology? I can't see any reason why I would have to use this.

Also I just tried to remove the `scalar` and it still worked without any difference, warnings or erros whatsoever. Would be grateful for any clarification or further resources on this topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `std140` and `std430` layouts do quite a bit of rounding of the offsets/alignments sizes of objects. `std140` basically makes any non-scalar type aligned to the same alignment as a `vec4`. `std430` relaxes that somewhat, but it still does a lot of rounding up to a `vec4`'s alignment.

`scalar` layout means basically to layout the objects in accord with their component scalars. Anything that aggregates components (vectors, matrices, arrays, and `struct`s) does not affect layout. In particular:

1. All types are sized/aligned only to the highest alignment of the scalar components that they actually use. So a struct containing a single `uint` is sized/aligned to the same size/alignment as a `uint`: 4 bytes. Under `std140` rules, it would have 16-byte size and alignment.

   Note that this layout [makes `vec3` and similar types actually viable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38172696/734069), because C and C++ would then be capable of creating alignment rules that map to those of GLSL.
2. The array stride of elements in the array is based solely on the size/alignment of the element type, recursively. So an array of `uint` has an array stride of 4 bytes; under `std140` rules, [it would have a 16-byte stride](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59829725/734069).
3. Alignment and padding only matter for scalars. If you have a struct containing a `uint` followed by a `uvec2`, in `std140/430`, this will require 16 bytes, with 4 bytes of padding after the first `uint`. Under `scalar` layout, such a struct only takes 12 bytes (and is aligned to 4 bytes), with the `uvec2` being conceptually misaligned. Padding therefore only exists if you have smaller scalars, like a `uint16` followed by a `uint`.

In the specific case you showed, `scalar` layout was unnecessary since all of the types you used are `vec4`s.

Comment: Thanks that calrifies a lot. Then I've probably missed some other part in the setup of vulkan, since the validation layer complained about the old layout of `Vector` which wasn't aligned to 16-byte blocks. But if it works this and I understand why way I'm happy :)

Comment: Under std430, isn't the struct alignment equal to the largest alignment of any of its members? Where is that 16-byte stride coming from?